# How to get element inside embedded html jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

> Main html

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
      <h1>Main</h1>
      <object type="text/html" width=100% height=100% data="./emb.html" id="dom"></object>
    </body>
</html>
```

> Other html

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
       <h1 id="emb">Embedded html</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to change some of elements styles inside the **object** tag by using jquery.

What i have tried is `$("#dom").find("#emb");` and it doesn't work
Thanks so much for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you must add a jquery version in your main html page. Also use .contents() and load() to get the object elements like,

```
// wait until your object loads
$('#dom').load(function() {
    // find the element needed
    emb = $(this).contents().find('#emb');
    alert(emb.html()); // for testing
});
```

Full code,

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
      <h1>Main</h1>
      <object type="text/html" width=100% height=100% data="./emb.html" id="dom"></object>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>
          $(function(){
              // wait until your object loads
              $('#dom').load(function() {
                // find element whose id is emb
                emb = $(this).contents().find('#emb');
                alert(emb.text()); // for testing
              });
          });
      </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It doesn't show the alert box, I tried to view it in console but it still doesn't show anything

Comment: `$('#dom').load(function() { //doesn't work});`
`$(window).load(function () { //work});`

I want use with `#dom`